# Nifi instances in docker containers doesn't start

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I have a gcp so i had made two dockers to look them like instances in a cluster with nifi installed on it. I'm able to run them individually but as soon as i run them as complete cluster by changing zookeeper and nifi properties it stops working gives me the below error.

I had already cleared my provenance repo but still getting the same error . I was following the link from [here](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/comment-page-1/)

**Logs from one the instance**

```
2018-08-24 05:45:20,296 INFO [main] o.a.n.p.PersistentProvenanceRepository Created new Provenance Event Writers for events starting with ID 0 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,309 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Maximum Threshold for Container default set to 108218562150 bytes; if volume exceeds this size, archived data will be deleted until it no longer exceeds this size 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,310 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Initializing FileSystemRepository with 'Always Sync' set to false 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,652 INFO [main] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@5a8ef07 finished recovering records. Performing Checkpoint to ensure proper state of Partitions before updates 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,652 INFO [main] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog Successfully recovered 4288 records in 38 milliseconds 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,677 INFO [main] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@5a8ef07 checkpointed with 4288 Records and 0 Swap Files in 24 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 6 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 2 millis), max Transaction ID 1475996 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,746 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Not enabling RAW Socket Site-to-Site functionality because nifi.remote.input.socket.port is not set 
2018-08-24 05:45:20,779 WARN [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@477b1fca{/nifi-api,file:///nifi/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.6.0.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.6.0.war} 
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller. 
at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:777) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292) 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084) 
at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55) 
... 33 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084) 
at org.apache.nifi.spring.StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.getObject(StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.java:48) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) 
... 39 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:350) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.<init>(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:55) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.create(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:189) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:608) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createClusteredInstance(FlowController.java:445) 
at org.apache.nifi.spring.FlowControllerFactoryBean.getObject(FlowControllerFactoryBean.java:63) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) 
... 46 common frames omitted 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,495 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=445ms 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,498 INFO [main] o.e.j.C./nifi-content-viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,535 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@49c45057{/nifi-content-viewer,file:///nifi/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.6.0.war} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,563 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@2c85c878{/nifi-docs,null,AVAILABLE} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,616 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=33ms 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,619 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.ContextHandler./nifi-docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,668 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47287357{/nifi-docs,file:///nifi/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.6.0.war} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,717 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=31ms 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,751 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.ContextHandler./ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,757 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@aa8284e{/,file:///nifi/nifi-1.6.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.6.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.6.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.6.0.war} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,785 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@727b060{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8051} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,785 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @61390ms 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,786 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down. 
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller. 
at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) 
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:777) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71) 
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292) 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084) 
at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55) 
... 33 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084) 
at org.apache.nifi.spring.StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.getObject(StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.java:48) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) 
... 39 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ./state/zookeeper/myid file is missing 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:350) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.<init>(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:55) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.create(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:189) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:608) 
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createClusteredInstance(FlowController.java:445) 
at org.apache.nifi.spring.FlowControllerFactoryBean.getObject(FlowControllerFactoryBean.java:63) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) 
... 46 common frames omitted 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,788 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server... 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,794 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@727b060{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8051} 
2018-08-24 05:45:21,795 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session Stopped scavenging
```

**Zookeeper properties**

```
clientPort=2181
initLimit=10
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
syncLimit=5
tickTime=2000
dataDir=./state/zookeeper
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30

#
# Specifies the servers that are part of this zookeeper ensemble. For
# every NiFi instance running an embedded zookeeper, there needs to be
# a server entry below. For instance:
#
# server.1=nifi-node1-hostname:2888:3888
# server.2=nifi-node2-hostname:2888:3888
# server.3=nifi-node3-hostname:2888:3888
#
# The index of the server corresponds to the myid file that gets created
# in the dataDir of each node running an embedded zookeeper. See the
# administration guide for more details.
#

server.1=<server-ip>:2888:3888
server.2=<server-ip>:2888:3888
```

Comment: The error log clearly says that the `myid` is missing. Running in a clustered mode requires ZooKeeper to be up with a valid and unique `myid` at `./state/zookeeper/`

Comment: I have checked it and is present with 1 and 2 as the values in two different docker instances

Comment: Does the  `state` directory exist within the NiFi location? Can you share the zookeeper.properties?

Comment: Added the zookeeper properties and yes state directory exist in nifi loc